# Angular2 lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

Am using lazy loaded modules in my angular2 application, the url of the lazy loaded module contains a # sign (for example http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard). I should authenticate with google and specify the callback url to my site, the problem is that google doesn't accept the sign #in the url, i wonder if there is a way to omit the # sign from the url of a lazy loaded module in angular2

Comment: Once you build with webpack or angular-cli, I believe what you're describing becomes a *.chunk.js.  But if you are talking about routing there is `{ useHash: false }`.

Comment: yes i dit that in the AppRoutingModule with  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false } )], and i specified the vase ref="/" in the index.html but still showing the hashes (# )